# Custom ArrayList serialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, classnotfound

I was trying to serialize an `ArrayList` which contains custom objects.

I'm serializing it in a `Servlet` (server side), and deserialize at the client side. (using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`)

It worked fine, when I work with `ArrayList<String>`.
But when I tried it with `ArrayList<MyObject>` I couldn't get any results in the client side, this is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: web.MyObject
```

Of course I have done this:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable { ... }
```

`MyObject` contains only `String` fields.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,
Ray.

Comment: Make sure MyObject is in the classpath of your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that your client doesnt know your MyObject when Deserialization. So you have to make sure that this class in also on the classpath.

Edit: oh sry i just saw that Anton was faster